# How to get the ThreadId in a custom target without using layout?

Tags: c#, nlog

I did create a custom-db-target to log to my database. It's a very simple target which only overrides the `Write` method to create a log-entry in my db.

This works fine and all informations are delivered by the `LogEventInfo`.

But now i want to log the threadId. As far as I know, NLog has the layout-parameter `${threadid}` to do so. But i don't want to use a layout-renderer to write into my db.

#### My Question

Is it possible to ask the `LogEventInfo` for the `threadId`? If yes: How? If no: Where does NLog get this id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create property (preferred) or variable with the threadId layout and render that one.

e.g.

```
Layout threadIdLayout = "${threadid}"; //for performance, as static property on the custom class is recommend

var threadId = threadIdLayout.Render(logEvent);
```

Comment: Totally correct. I think i thought to complicated and tried to avoid the render too much :D